# Destructuring items that have additonal properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to see is there a bette way off destructing this prop.

I'm getting data from a weather API, and it's being passed to a component through props. The full object is `this.props.weather.Temperature.Maximum.Value;`

I'm currently destructing it like so

`const {Maximum, Minimum} = this.props.weather.Temperature;`

I have to call it like this as theres an additional property afterwards.

`{Maximum.value}`

Is there a better way to destructure this? Or is this approach fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try destructuring the object more to get the value of both `Maximum` and `Minimum`

```
const { Maximum: { Value: MaximumValue }, Minimum: { Value: MinimumValue } } = this.props.weather.Temperature
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
console.log(MaximumValue, MinimumValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
props = {  
    attraction: {
      address1: "350 5th Ave",
      address2: "",
      average_rating: 4,
      city: "New York",
      country: "US",
      display_address: ["350 5th Ave", "New York, NY 10118"],
      id: 9,
      latitude_coordinate: "40.748442285082",
      location: {
        created_at: "2018–03–07T03:56:20.717Z",
        id: 1,
        latitude_coordinate: 40.712775,
        longitude_coordinate: -74.005973,
        ...
      }
    },
    auth: {
      loggedIn: true,
      loggingIn: false,
      ...
    } ...
  }
```

**sample props which i want to pass in my comp**

```
const Attraction = ({
  auth, 
  auth: { token },
  attraction: { id, url_name, name, image_url, average_rating }
}) => {
  return (
    <div auth={auth} key={id}>
      <Link token={token} to={`/attractions/${url_name}`} key={id}>
        <img alt={name} src={image_url} />
        <h1>{name}</h1>
      </Link>
      <StarRatings rating={average_rating} />
    </div>
  );
};`enter code here`
```